Double TextBox in Shape using DrawingObject.Formula
When my macro runs, it links values in some cells, then I use those cell values in shapes with DrawingObject.Formula. This way I can only get to the shape to look like the right square, but i would need it to have the second value right below it(see image)
Range("E1").Value = Data
Var1 = Range("E2").Value
Var2 = Range("E3").Value
Var3 = Range("E5").Value
Var4 = Range("F7").Value
Var5 = Range("F8").Value
Var6 = Range("F9").Value
Var7 = Range("E8").Value


wsLP.Shapes(ArrayColBloco(0)).DrawingObject.Formula = "=E1"
wsLP.Shapes(ArrayColBloco(1)).DrawingObject.Formula = "=E2"
wsLP.Shapes(ArrayColBloco(2)).DrawingObject.Formula = "=E3"
wsLP.Shapes(ArrayColBloco(3)).DrawingObject.Formula = "=E5"
wsLP.Shapes(ArrayColBloco(4)).DrawingObject.Formula = "=F5"
wsLP.Shapes(ArrayColBloco(5)).DrawingObject.Formula = "=F6"
wsLP.Shapes(ArrayColBloco(6)).DrawingObject.Formula = "=F7"
wsLP.Shapes(ArrayColBloco(7)).DrawingObject.Formula = "=E8"


Probably would need another way to link the cell values to the shapes textbox

One option if you can use a (hidden) "helper" sheet is to format cells there as you want, then use the "Camera" tool to create linked snapshots of those cells which can be positioned on another sheet.  You may need to add the Camera tool to your ribbon since I don't think it's there by default.  https://officeproductivitytraining.com/our-blog/f/excel%E2%80%99s-hidden-secret-the-camera-tool

...be aware though that the Camera tool can cause your workbook to lag if you use it for too many shapes.

@TimWilliams This solution is to weird that it's already brilliant again. But how do you put the outcome of the camera tool onto a shape?

The tool creates the shape I think - you have to format the source range to match how you want it to look

@TimWilliams wow, didnt know something like that existed, thanks!

In VBA you can copy a range then use ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste(Link:=True) (can be a different sheet from the source range) to create a linked picture.  Same result as using the camera tool.

o It is not possible to put a formula as source to a shape that contains more than a single cell reference, see Text And Formula In Shape Text. So something like "=E2" & char(10) & F2" will fail - in Excel, you get an error message "The formula is missing a cell reference...". If you try this with code, you get a runtime error 1004 "Unable to set the Formula property..."
o You could use a helper cell (maybe on a hidden sheet or a hidden column) that has the formula, and reference that cell.
Formula in Z2: =E2 & char(10) & F2
Formula for the shape: =Z2
o When you use cell references as content for a shape, you can't format the characters individually, it's an "all or nothing". So you can't have the first part in bold+red and the second part in black font as you show in your picture.
o I would advice to simply use 2 shapes - put a small shape inside the shape you have, make it transparent (and no border, but do this only after you are sure everything works as it is hard to find an invisible shape on top of another).


Thanks for the ideia, but i couldnt make the Z2 formula work, could you redo it? I tried manualy using CARACTUNICODE(10) but it doesnt break the line and in VBA the code wont work.

A line break in Excel is done with the character 10 (Linefeed). Char(10) will add that, so you have to lines in the cell (you need to set WordWrap so that you can see it. Note that this an Formula in Excel, not something written with VBA.

thanks!!! i was having difficulties because of the difference in syntax caused by the excel language

Alternative approach based on the "Camera" tool, if you can create a range with the required content and styled the way you want the graphic to appear.
Camera tool: https://officeproductivitytraining.com/our-blog/f/excel%E2%80%99s-hidden-secret-the-camera-tool
Also can do this from the Paste ribbon button:

A VBA method to simulate that effect:
Sub Tester()

   AddLinkedRangeImage Sheet5.Range("A1:C4"), Sheet2.Range("B11")
    
End Sub

Sub AddLinkedRangeImage(rngSrc As Range, rngDest As Range)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = rngDest.Worksheet
    rngSrc.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap
    ws.Paste
    With ws.Shapes(ws.Shapes.Count)
        .Top = rngDest.Cells(1).Top
        .Left = rngDest.Cells(1).Left
        .DrawingObject.Formula = _
          "'" & rngSrc.Parent.Name & "'!" & rngSrc.Address()
    End With
End Sub

A bit simpler if you use:
sheetReferenceHere.Pictures.Paste(Link:=True)
but I wanted to show use of the .DrawingObject.Formula property.
